# Quartz scheduler execute an Runnable

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz

**Can a Quartz Scheduler execute a Runnable?**

For example, I have the following code being running by a spring `TaskScheduler`:

```
[...]
@Autowired
@Qualifier(IntegrationConfiguration.TASK_SCHEDULER_INTEGRATION_NAME)
private TaskScheduler taskScheduler;

[...]
ScheduledFuture<?> scheduledFuture = taskScheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            execucaoJobService.executa(jobName, execucaoJobDto, jobScheduleId);
        } catch (JobExecutionException e) {
            LOG.error("Job Execution fails", e);
        }
    }
}, new CronTrigger(cronExpression));
[...]
```

I wanna do something like the above code with Quartz, I know there is QuartzJobBean class, but this one
only works with static code, and I need to pass the cronExpression and other params dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a job that takes a `Runnable` via the `JobDataMap`, and run that on execution.

The job would look like this:

```java
public final class RunnableJob implements Job {

    public static final String RUNNABLE_KEY = "RUNNABLE_KEY";

    public RunnableJob() {
        // Explicit constructor is required by Quartz.
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) {
        final var runnable = (Runnable) jobExecutionContext.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap().get(RUNNABLE_KEY);
        runnable.run();
    }
}
```

Where you schedule your job it would look something like this:

```java
        final var cronTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(cronExpression))
            .build();

        final var jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(RunnableJob.class)
            .setJobData(new JobDataMap(Map.of(RunnableJob.RUNNABLE_KEY,
                (Runnable) () -> {
                    // Do whatever you want to do
                })))
            .build();

        scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, cronTrigger);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this code:  [QuartzScheduledExecutorService.java](https://github.com/Audumla/audiot-java-things/blob/382283a3f2a382890ff5cb1f4ee6d02ec69f39bf/quartz/src/main/java/net/audumla/scheduler/quartz/QuartzScheduledExecutorService.java) that helps me with this problem. maybe it can help someone else in the future.